# How to change the size of some ArrayList in a 2d ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have this class to implement a 2d `ArrayList`. I want the method `criaDimensao()` to put values inside the `ArrayList` at index position of `matriz` only but it keeps putting value in all indexes of `matriz`.

```
public class Matriz {
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matriz = new ArrayList<>();

    //constructor
    public Matriz(){

    }

    //constructor
    public Matriz(int lenght){
        int c = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> init = new ArrayList<>();
        while (c < lenght){
            matriz.add(init);
            c +=1 ;
        }
    }

    public boolean criaDimensao(int index, int tamanhoDimensao){
        for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoDimensao; i++){
            matriz.get(index).add(0); //defalt value 0
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The idea is to have different sizes of `ArrayList` inside the `matriz`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the constructor:

```
ArrayList<Integer> init = new ArrayList<>();
while (c < lenght){
    matriz.add(init);
    c +=1 ;
}
```

You keep on adding a reference to the *same* `ArrayList` in all indices of `matriz`. So when you call:

```
matriz.get(index).add(0);
```

You will be adding it to `init`, which will be reflected across the entire `mariz`

Instead you could have something like this in the constructor:

```
while (c < lenght){
   matriz.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
   c +=1 ;
}
```